# Where is the list of supported device emulations in KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am configuring a guest VM under libvirt using virsh edit.  The source of the kernel running in the VM is an embedded security device where I have no control over what drivers it comes with.  In particular it doesn't seem to recognize the **virtio** driver for the NIC so I am using the **e1000** emulation shown as follows:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:ae:cd:b2'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

This value was copied from an example I found on the web somewhere.

I want to experiment to try other emulations to see what works best, but I haven't been able to find what options there are.   This applies to both the disk and the network devices.  I wouldn't mind known what video emulations are available either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of some of the available emulations are shown on the man page for **kvm**.  For a definitive list for the system in use, use the **kvm** command as follows:

```
kvm -net nic,model=?
```

On my system that results in the following output:

```
kvm -net nic,model=?
qemu: Supported NIC models: ne2k_pci,i82551,i82557b,i82559er,rtl8139,e1000,pcnet,virtio
```

For people who are following the same learning curve as I am, it helps to understand how the **virsh** command does its job.  The XML definition file is parsed into a **kvm** command when you execute a **virsh start xxx** command.   The actual command that it is transformed into along with environment variables is logged in **/var/log/libvirt/qemu/xxx.log** where **xxx** is the domain name of your guest VM.

So with this architecture the list of available options doesn't need to be defined by the **virsh** package since it is basically an abstraction for the real work going on which is done by **kvm**.  Not knowing that made me look for documentation the wrong places.

Comment: `kvm nic model=help` on newer qemu's